# Where do I ask for a suggestion of a movie/documentary about running for office?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, policy

I want to ask for a movie that would show the negative aspects of running for office in the U.S.  I believe you cannot ask for the identification of a movie on movies.stackexchange.com.  Would it be ok to ask this on politics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I can't talk about Politics.SE, but I _think_ recommendations are often not a good fit for SE sites. However, as you've got 31 rep elsewhere, you can access any chat room and ask there (including Movies.SE's :) ) - not sure though, hence why this is a comment

Answer (score 7):

You are seeking a movie recommendation, and so I think that your question will not be on-topic for any site on the Stack Exchange network.